# JavaFX tableView content from wekaapi is missing

Tags: java, javafx, weka

I've got big problem with visualiation of arff files in javaFX table view. My code :

```
    ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
    loader.setFile(arff);
    Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
    List<TableColumn<Instance, String>> atrributes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.numAttributes(); i++) {
                 atrributes.add(new TableColumn<Instance,String>` (data.attribute(i).name()));

    }
    List <Instance> instances = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i =0;i<data.size();i++)
    {
        instances.add(data.get(i));
    }
    ObservableList<Instance> tableContent = FXCollections.observableArrayList(instances);
    table.getColumns().removeAll();
    table.getColumns().addAll(atrributes);
    table.setItems(tableContent);
    table.setVisible(true);
```

Names of columns(attributes) are set properly but contest is not shwon(tableContent variable)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a cell value factory for each table column. This is a function that maps the `Instance` in each row to the value to be displayed in the corresponding cell in that column.

I am not familiar with Weka, but looking at the [Javadocs](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/core/Instance.html), I think you need

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.numAttributes(); i++) {
    TableColumn<Instance, String> column 
        = new TableColumn<Instance,String>(data.attribute(i).name());
    final int attIndex = i ;
    column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
        new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().toString(attIndex)));
    atrributes.add(column);

}
```